# Java Running A Constructor from a Subclass

Tags: java, constructor, attributes, subclass

This is my class Mappa, it has mappaName as the main attribute of the constructor

```
public class Mappa {
    private Name mappaName;
    protected Settore [][] settore;
    private int Matrice [][];
    private static final int X=14;
    private static final int Y=23;
    public Mappa (Name mappaName){
        this.mappaName=mappaName;
        settore = new Settore[X][Y];
        for (int i=0; i < X; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<Y; j++) {
                settore[i][j] = new Settore (i,j);
            }
        }
        Matrice = new int[X][Y];
        if(mappaName==Name.FERMI){
            settore[8][10]=new Alieni(8,10);
            settore[9][10]=new Umani(9,10);
        }
        if(mappaName==Name.GALILEI||mappaName==Name.GALVANI){
            settore[5][10]=new Alieni(5,10);
            settore[7][10]=new Umani(7,10);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the subclass MappaFermi, which only runs the constructor of the class Mappa setting mappaName as Name.FERMI

```
public class MappaFermi extends Mappa {
    public MappaFermi() {
        super(null);
        new Mappa(Name.FERMI);
    }
```

Isn't `new Mappa(Name.FERMI);` supposed to set `mappaName` as `Name.FERMI` and because of the if condition setting `settore[8][10]=new Alieni(8,10);` and `settore[9][10]=new Umani(9,10);`? because when i make tests it returns null instead of the expected values.

```
public class MappaFermiTest {
    @Test
    public void testMappaFermiNome(){
        Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi();
        assertEquals(Name.FERMI, mappa.getMappaName());
    }
    @Test
    public void testMappaFermiAlieni(){
        Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi();
        assertEquals(Nome.ALIENI, mappa.getSettori()[8][10].getSettoreNome());
    }
}
```

Comment: This `new Mappa(Name.FERMI);` create a **new** instance.

Comment: I would also like to request that in the future, please translate your variable and method names to English for questions.

Comment: SIde note on code quality: your constructor is doing to many things. Having those if blocks in there ... smells wrong. Then: hardcoding **some** of the indices like you do ... well, stinks wrong. Don't do that. If you really think that using specific indices for such purposes is OK for you; then at least use constants. Plus: variable names should start with lower case letters.

Comment: @mpz And +1 for Dragondraikk: you come back with new questions on your source code every hour;  looks like you want to use Stackoverflow to answer all problems on your program that you can't figure yourself. Then at least show some **respect** and translate your program content to the preferred language here.

Answer (score 1):

You seem slightly mistaken about what the `new` keyword does.

`new` calls a constructor and returns a **new instance of the class**. This means that your

```
public MappaFermi() {
    super(null);
    new Mappa(Name.FERMI);
}
```

actually creates a new `Mappa` object after calling `super` (which is the *actual* parent constructor call) and then discards it.

You actually wanted to do

```
public MappaFermi() {
    super(Name.FERMI);
}
```

Comment: For further clarification: a class's parent class is called superclass, hence the term ``super`` what is usable within a subclass's constructor.